# Webpack Dev Server not compiling on change (imported CSS)

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2, postcss, postcss-import

I have the following folder structure

```
src/
  assets/
    css/
      subfolder/
        imported.css
      main.css (-> imports "imported.css" with "postcss-import")
  components/
    Component1.vue
  App.vue (imports "main.css")
  main.js
```

I'm using `vue-loader` to compile the `.vue` files. In App.vue, I'm importing the `main.css` file (which imports multiple other css files, e.g. normalize and a simple grid system, with postcss-import).

```
<template>

</template>

<script>

</script>

<style src="./assets/css/main.css"></style>
```

To compile everything, I'm using Webpack and Webpack Dev Server with the following config:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          postcss: [
            require('postcss-import')(),
            require('postcss-cssnext')(),
            require('postcss-reporter')()
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.css', '.vue']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}
```

This works just fine for every file except my `imported.css` file. Whenever I modify and save it, Webpack (Dev Server) doesn't recompile my assets. I have to manually switch to my `main.css` file or any `.vue` file an save that file to recompile. Is there any way to recompile assets even if I save my `imported.css` file?

Answer (score 1):

Older versions of `postcss-import` accepted the [`addDependencyTo`](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-import#adddependencyto) option, but it has been deprecated for newer versions used in combination with `postcss-loader`, though I wonder if it still may be relevant in your case.

You would pass the loader context and `postcss-import` would call [`ctx.addDependency`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/loaders.html#adddependency) to tell Webpack that `imported.css` is a dependency of `main.css`.

Without this, you would get the kind of behavior that you're experiencing, that Webpack isn't watching and recompiling on changes in imported modules.

Comment: Thanks, do I have to use `ctx.addDependency` for every imported CSS file (quite a few in my case) or is there any other way to include a bunch of files? Since this method is deprecated, I'm also wondering what I'd do if this  methods gets removed at some point (I looked at the `postcss-loader` docs but I'm not sure how I would include this with `vue-loader`)?

Comment: @Daniel looking at some of the open/closed issues in the `vue-loader` repository, indeed this seems to be the root cause. I'm not sure whether there is a working setup for PostCSS that would support HMR or if you'll have to wait for some PR to enable this.